# Missing Extensibility VSIX project template

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, project-template, missing-template

I'm trying to add a VSIX Project to my solution but there is no Project Templates under Extensions:

[image]

I searched for Extension in the Components and can't find any Extension to install:

[image]

**How do I get the VSIX projects?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Visual Studio SDK as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/installing-the-visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2022

[image]

And then they're available:

[image]